# instantiating an inner class from the main method

Tags: instantiation, inner-classes

How can I instantiate an inner class?  for example:

```
    QuoteArray quotes1 = new QuoteArray(1);

    QuoteArray.Quote quote1 = new QuoteArray.Quote("quote","char","actor","film","year");//error here
```

Where Quote is an inner class of QuoteArray. None of this really makes sense to me.  I know how to instantiate Quote from within QuoteArray, but I don't know how to do this in my main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QuoteArray.Quote quote1 = new QuoteArray().new Quote("quote","char","actor","film","year");
```

Well this makes no sense to me, but it works.